# fastest way to display mysql db records

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have slow query problem, may be i am wrong, here is what i want,

i have to display more than 40 drop down lists at a single page with same fields , fetched by db, but i feel that the query takes much time to execute and also use more resources..

here is an example...

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
$rows = mysql_query($sql_query);
```

now i use while loop to print all records in that query in drop down list,

but i have to reprint same record in next drop down list up to 40 lists, so i use

`mysql_data_seek()` to move to first record and then reprint the next list and so on till 40 lists.

but this was seems slow to me so i use the second method like this same query for all 40 lists

```
$sql_query2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
$rows2 = mysql_query($sql_query2);
```

do you think that i wrong about the speed of query, or do you suggest me the another way that is faster than these methods....

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the rows into an array like so:

```
<?php
$rows = array();

$fetch_rows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_rows)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Then just use the `$rows` array in a `foreach ($rows as $row)` loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is considerable processing overhead associated with fetching rows from a MySQL result resource.  Typically it would be quite a bit faster to store the results as an array in PHP rather than to query and fetch the same rowset again from the RDBMS.

```
$rowset = array();
$result = mysql_query(...);
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Append each fetched row onto $rowset
    $rowset[] = $row;
  }
}
```

If your query returns lots of rows (thousands or tens of thousands or millions) and you need to use all of them, you may reach memory limitations by storing all rows into an array in PHP.  In that case it may be more memory-conservative to fetch rows individually from MySQL, but it will still probably be more CPU intensive.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of printing the records, going back, and printing them again, put the records in one big string variable, then echo it for each dropdown.

```
$str = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
    // instead of echo...
    $str .= [...];
}
// now for each dropdown
echo $str;
// will print all the rows.
```